# Player Movement Direction Logic

Tags: java, libgdx, logic, game-engine

Consider points A and B as walls and point O as player inside walls.

So they look like A O B.

I want player to move left when he touches rightPoint B. And move right when he touches leftPoint A.

The screen is being rendered and player position is either incremented by 5 for right direction or by -5 for left direction.

What I tried to do:
I put it in if else if statement. If distance between A and O is zero, player position gets +5 incrementation. If distance between O and B is zero, player position gets -5 incrementation. But as soon as he touches a wall(say right wall), he moves back -5 and then 5 and again -5 and then 5.

I understand why this is happening but I do not have any logic to implement this.

CODE:
Sorry I could not post actual code. Im on mobile internet. I dont have computer internet.

Suppose leftwall at 50, 0 and rightwall at 550, 0 and player at 50, 0.

//this all is being rendered.

```
If (rightWall - PlayerPos <=0){
    PosIncrement = -5;
}
If (leftWall - PlayerPos <=0){
    PosIncrement = 5;
}
translateX (PlayerPos);
```

Comment: maybe the gap between the walls is only 5 units?

Comment: Its happening because as soon as player leaves current wall to go to another direction, the other if statement gets executed and he moves back -5. He collides wih wall and gets 5 increment. But again leaving the wall executes other if statement and he get -5 again. Distance between walls is 500pixels.

Comment: Would be easier if you added your code to the question

Comment: if player leaves wall, and distance between them is 500, why should any if statement execute? they should both evaluate to false.

Comment: Distance between walls is 500. Distance between player and left wall is zero.

Comment: why is the comparison <= and not == ? if player is betwen walls then one wall position is always smaller then player's position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If player should be **between** walls, it implies that the left wall should always have a position that is lower the the player position.  Player position shuld be equal or larger than 50 and equal or smaller 550

so the correct logic can be

```
If (rightWall - PlayerPos <=0){
    PosIncrement = -5;
}
If (PlayerPos - leftWall <=0){
    PosIncrement = 5;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I solved the question. The playerPos was reseting in rendering method. Also, my logic was incorrect for leftwall. It works now.